# Embedding Authenticated Mongo Charts in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x, mongodb, jwt, embedded-mongodb

I am trying to embed Mongo Charts in Reactjs in an Authenticated manner using Python3 Flask  for creating JWT.

BAckend - Python Flask

```
header = {
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
forToken = {}
forToken["firstname"] = user["firstname"]
forToken["exp"] = ((datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=10)))
jwtapp = jwt.encode(forToken, SECRET_KEY, algorithm='HS256', headers=header)
// SECRET_KEY is same as that provided in Mongo Atlast Auth Provider section
hyphenuser["token"] = jwtapp
```

ReactJS code - loginVerify.js
As soon as user login, token is fetched from backend api and is stored in localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem("token", (response?.token))
```

ReactJS code - chart.js

```
const sdk2 = new ChartsEmbedSDK ( {
       baseUrl: "https://charts.mongodb.com/charts-mythila-bang-ihtjk",
       getUserToken: () => localStorage.getItem("token"),
       filter: {
          "organization": { "$eq": response?.organization }
       }    
  });

...........
...........
return (

   <div id="SOA_chart2" class="column chartMongo"> </div>  
);
```

In the Mongo Atlas, I have created the chart by enabling Authentication

[Authentication Provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPzqm.png)

[Enabled Authentication and added Auth Provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53T4P.png)

However when I access the application, I receive the following error message and chart does not load

> Error loading data for this chart (error code: 10). JWT has no
> matching providers. See
> https://dochub.mongodb.org/core/charts-embedding-error-codes for
> details.
>
> host.js:330 Uncaught (in promise) Error:
> {"errorCode":10,"simple":"Error loading data for this chart (error
> code: 10).","verbose":"Error loading data for this chart (error code:
> 10). JWT has no matching providers.